# "Could not find resource" when trying to retrieve latest build artifact

Tags: artifactory

In my Artifactory repo I want to retrieve the latest build artifact.
Described at this link REST API
https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-RetrieveLatestArtifact

My target artifact (name of the package **ADS_*.zip**) I can download if I specify version explicitly:

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Headers @{'X-JFrog-Art-Api'=$API_KEY}
"$ARTIFACTORY_URL/ADS/ADS_2019_4_1.zip" 
-OutFile "$DOWNLOAD_PATH\ADS.zip"
```

But if I try methods which were suggested on the link using the **[RELEASE]** or **[INTERGATION]** or **[SNAPSHOT]**:

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Headers @{'X-JFrog-Art-Api'=$API_KEY} 
"$ARTIFACTORY_URL/ADS/ADS_[RELEASE].zip"
-OutFile "$DOWNLOAD_PATH\ADS.zip"
```

I am getting the:

```
"status" : 404,
"message" : "Could not find resource"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

To use this feature, you should configure and use a repository layout.
You can read [here](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Repository+Layouts) for instructions on how to do that. More specifically, see `baseRev`.

However, configuring a repository layout is not always the best option, since it affects all artifacts in the repository. It is also a bit complicated.

Instead, I'd recommend using the [JFrog CLI](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/JFrog+CLI) for downloading artifacts, instead of the REST API.

```sh
jf rt dl <path-in-artifactory> <local-path> --sort-by updated --limit 1 --url <jfrog-platform-url>/artifactory --user <username> --password <api-key>
```

For example, in your case:

```sh
jf rt dl "ADS/ADS_*.zip" "$DOWNLOAD_PATH\ADS.zip" --sort-by updated --limit 1 --url <jfrog-platform-url>/artifactory --user <username> --password <api-key>
```

For more information see [Downloading files](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/CLI+for+JFrog+Artifactory#CLIforJFrogArtifactory-DownloadingFiles).

Comment: can I instakk JFrog CLI on external server from where I planned to execute REST API calls?

Comment: Yes, @AndreyDonald. You can download it with one commend. See https://jfrog.com/getcli